# How to create a secret in a Docker Vault container

Tags: docker, containers, hashicorp-vault

I'm familiar with how to create, get, delete, etc secrets in a Vault server running on dev mode (by this I mean all the command line prompts and commands that are used from creating/starting the server, setting the vault address and root token, and then actually working with secrets).

How exactly would I do this with a Vault container? Using the same steps for a Vault server doesn't work, so I'm guessing that I'm missing some step along the way that's necessary for containers but not servers.

Do I have to create a shell script or use docker-compose, or is there any way I could create/start a Vault container and save secrets in it all with terminal commands?

Comment: Have you tried following the documentation on the Vault dockerhub page? That might be the best starting point. https://hub.docker.com/_/vault#:~:text=Running%20Vault%20for%20Development

Comment: @NickSchroeder While running a container with the run command the page lists goes without any problems, it still doesn't answer my question of how to actually run a vault command and create a secret. Docker will create and run the container, but won't let me add any secrets to it.

Comment: "won't let me"... might be best to update the question with the full error details and more technical info on the scenario you're having trouble with.